# How to get the oldest data where three SQL tables are involved

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, **Items**, **Orders** and a many-to-many linking table called **ItemOrders**.
Each item can have many orders and of course an order can have many items.

I need a list of item that returns:

- fields from the Items table
- fields from the Orders table

but only for the oldest order for each item.  I've tried all manner of joins and sub-queries but just can't get my head round how to do this.

For example, **Items**:

```
+--------+---------------+
| ItemId |   ItemName    |
+--------+---------------+
|     1  | Crisps        |
|     2  | Chocolate Bar |
+--------+---------------+
```

**ItemOrders**:

```
+--------+---------+
| ItemId | OrderId |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |      21 |
|      1 |      22 |
|      2 |      23 |
|      2 |      24 |
|      2 |      22 |
+--------+---------+
```

and **Orders**:

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| OrderId | OrderDate  |  Name   |
+---------+------------+---------+
|      21 | 2019-03-12 | ORD2501 |
|      22 | 2019-03-20 | ORD2502 |
|      23 | 2019-03-28 | ORD2503 |
|      24 | 2019-03-31 | ORD2504 |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
+---------------+-----------+
|   ItemName    | OrderName |
+---------------+-----------+
| Crisps        | ORD2501   |
| Chocolate Bar | ORD2502   |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Any help on the correct approach would be most appreciated. This is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Try using row_number with order by orderId

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not fields. (In the SQL world.)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `CROSS APPLY` with a `TOP (1)`and `ORDER BY` in it:

```sql
SELECT I.itemName,
       OD.OrderId
FROM dbo.Items I
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) O.[Name]
                  FROM dbo.ItemOrders OI
                       JOIN dbo.Orders O ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID
                  WHERE OI.ItemID = I.ItemID
                  ORDER BY O.OrderDate DESC) OD;
```

Another approach is using `TOP (1) WITH TIES` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       I.ItemName,
       O.[Name]
FROM dbo.Items I
     JOIN dbo.ItemOrders OI ON OI.ItemID = I.ItemID
     JOIN dbo.Orders O ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.ItemID ORDER BY O.OrderDate DESC);
```

Or you can put `ROW_NUMBER` into a CTE, and then use a `WHERE` to filter:

```sql
WITH RN AS(
    SELECT I.ItemName,
           O.[Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.ItemID ORDER BY O.OrderDate DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Items I
         JOIN dbo.ItemOrders OI ON OI.ItemID = I.ItemID
         JOIN dbo.Orders O ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID)
SELECT ItemName,
       [Name]
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a lateral join:

```
select i.*, o.orderid
from items i outer apply
     (select top (1) o.*
      from itemOrders io join
           Orders o
           on io.orderid = o.orderid
      where io.itemid = i.itemid
      order by o.orderdate desc
     ) o
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But it runs very slowly. The CTE in the other answer ran very fast.

Comment: @FeridunKadir . . . Faster than this?  That surprises me a bit.  Do you have primary key declared on all the tables?